# How to create front end page in Spring Boot and REST API and sending data to database from that page?

Tags: hibernate, rest, jsp, spring-boot

Can anybody help me to create frontend page and accessing it through REST controller and then sending data from form in frontend page to REST controller to process and save in database?

Comment: Spring is for backend development, no?

Comment: Thanks for replying Aluan Haddad. Spring boot is for backend development only.. but i have created spring boot project.. now i have to create front end page and send data to database.. how it can be done?

Comment: It depends on how complicated the front end needs to be. If it's relatively interactive or needs to pull down dynamic data you will probably want to create a separate JavaScript application in its own project with its own tools. I'm not sure how spring-boot would help you with that it seems like it would be best approached as a separate endeavor

Answer (score 0):

Like Aluan Haddad said, it depends on your needs. But since you are new like me. I suggest thymeleaf to start. Its almost like html and quite easy to learn. You can find many examples on web. Like:
["this one"](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-thymeleaf/). It will help you improve yourself. Good luck.